Reverse the states of 2 git commits and rewrite the history
Imagine I am on branch feat and have a test.txt file that contains this content.
111

Then I made a commit B, adding these two lines.
  111
+ 222
+ 333

And the git history looks like this
A
|
B(origin/feat)  # adding 222, 333

Then I realized 333 should be on a different commit so it could be cherry-picked by another branch. So I created another commit to remove 333.
  111
  222
- 333

A 
|
B(origin/feat)  # adding 222, 333
|
C(feat)         # removing 333

Now is there a way to rewrite the history, to make the commit history look like this?
A
|
D               # adding 222 (state of C)
|
E(origin/feat)  # adding 333 (state of B)

I don't mind rewriting the history and force push, since I'm the only one working on this branch.

I don't see any way to do this, because the only possible commits we can come up with are: 1) adding 222 by itself, 2) adding 222 and 333 together.

But I have the states of commit B and C which I want to use, could there be a way to rewrite the history based on the states but not the diff?

The way with the fewest unfamiliar commands:
git checkout A
git read-tree -um C
git commit -m D
git read-tree -um B
git commit -m E

the way with less worktree churn:
D=$(git commit-tree -p A -m D C:)
git reset --hard $(git commit-tree -p $D -m E B:)

A worked example:
git init `mktemp -d`; cd $_
printf %s\\n 111 >file; git add .; git commit -mA
printf %s\\n 111 222 333 >file; git commit -amB
printf %s\\n 111 333 >file;     git commit -amC
# setup complete, now
D=$(git commit-tree -p :/A -m D @:)
git reset --hard $(git commit-tree -p $D -m E @^:)
git log --graph --oneline --all @{1}


Precisely what I needed, thank you so much about telling me the read-tree command!

An alternative to @jthill's solutions with the plumbing commands read-tree and commit-tree, could be by mixed-resetting to commit B, and then patch-adding the line with 222 with the edit option to commit this single change (commit D). Finally, you can commit the only change left (line 333) and obtain commit E.
# make sure to be on branch feat
git checkout feat

# mixed resetting to commit B
git reset --mixed HEAD~

# stage only the change with 222 with the edit option
git add --patch -- test.txt

# create commit D with only 222
git commit -m "D"

# staging the remaining changes
git add test.txt

# creating commit E with only 333
git commit -m "E"

